# TypeError: _This.props is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am new in react native please kindly help me to solve this problem:
TypeError: _props.goToScreen is not a function, please help me thank in advance

Profile.js i want to click on the GotoHome Button and go to another page

```
export default class Profile extends Component {
 _GotoHome = () => {
   this.props.goToScreen('UploadProduct');
 };

 render() {
   return (

         <ListItem icon>
           <Left>
             <Text>List All Uploaded Product</Text>
           </Left>
           <Body />
           <Right>
             <Icon
               active
               name="angle-right"
               type="FontAwesome"
               onPress={() => this._GotoHome()}
             />
           </Right>
         </ListItem>



   );
 }
}
```

this is my navigation in profile page Navigation\index.js

```
import {createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import UploadProductScreen from './UploadProductScreen';

const ProfileStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
    },
    UploadProduct: {
      screen: UploadProductScreen,
    },
  },
  {headerMode: 'none'},
);





export default createAppContainer(ProfileStackNavigator );
```

and here my uploadProductScreen page

```
import {UploadProduct} from '@container';

class UploadProductScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <UploadProduct
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        goToScreen={(screen, EventId) => navigate(screen, {ItemId: EventId})}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default UploadProductScreen;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in uploadProductScreenPage?

Comment: Thank for your answer i want to use "UploadProduct" instead of this.props.navigation.navigate("UploadProduct"), i know what is the problem now thank you

Answer (score 0):

define constructor in your Profie component to use props.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }
```

Also I use something like this to navigate to another screen.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("UploadProduct");   // here UploadProduct is the key yo have defined in stack navigator
```